# Spark-shell : The number of columns doesn't match

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have csv format file and is separated by delimiter pipe "|". And the dataset has 2 column, like below .

```
Column1|Column2
1|Name_a
2|Name_b
```

But sometimes we receive only one column value and other is missing like below

```
Column1|Column2
1|Name_a
2|Name_b
3
4
5|Name_c
6
7|Name_f
```

So any row having mismatched column no is a garbage value for us for the above example it will be rows having column value as `3, 4, and 6` and we want to discard these rows. Is there any direct way I can discard those rows, without having a exception while reading the data from spark-shell like below.

```
val readFile = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").csv("File.csv").toDF(Seq("Column1", "Column2"): _*)
```

When we are trying to read the file we are getting the below exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
Old column names (1): _c0
New column names (2): Column1, Column2
  at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.toDF(Dataset.scala:435)
  ... 49 elided
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify schema of your data file and allow some columns to be nullable. In scala it may look like:

```
val schm = StructType(
  StructField("Column1", StringType, nullable = true) ::
  StructField("Column3", StringType, nullable = true) :: Nil)

val readFile = spark.read.
option("delimiter", "|")
.schema(schm)
.csv("File.csv").toDF
```

Than you can filter your dataset by column is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `DROPMALFORMED` mode to the option as below, while reading. Setting this makes Spark to drop the corrupted records.

```
val readFile = spark.read
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") // Option to drop invalid rows.
  .csv("File.csv")
  .toDF(Seq("Column1", "Column2"): _*)
```

This is documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv-scala.collection.Seq-).

Comment: It didnt work .. still getting same issue .. even checked the doc :(

Comment: I believe mode:DROPMALFORMED  wouldn't work well without specifying schema of dataset