# Error while running python file : The number of columns doesn't match.\nOld column names (1): _c0\nNew column names (4)

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

When I run the below code, I had some error which says that The number of columns doesn't match.\nOld column names (1): _c0\nNew column names (4): As I am new to python, I want to know how to fix this issue :

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# create Spark context and session with necessary configuration
sc = SparkContext('local[1]', '2_program_2a_avg')
spark = SparkSession(sc)

# read as dataframe with using delimiter
df = spark.read \
     .format('csv') \
     .options(header='false', delimiter=' ') \
     .load('/home/hduser/Desktop/sample1/avg/input_avg.csv') \
     .toDF('ownerid','houseid','zipcode','value')

# select the necessary columns
df = df.select('zipcode', 'value')

# compute the average house value of each zipcode
df = df.groupBy('zipcode').agg(F.mean('value'), F.count('value')).orderBy('avg(value)', ascending=True)

# show the result
df.show()

# change it to rdd so that we can save the output as text file
df = df.rdd.saveAsTextFile('/home/hduser/Desktop/sample1/avg/')

# stop spark context
sc.stop()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
*/home/hduser/PycharmProjects/Assignment2/venv/bin/python /home/hduser/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/avg_value.py
    19/11/12 10:47:49 WARN Utils: Your hostname, hadoop resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface enp0s3)
    19/11/12 10:47:49 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
    19/11/12 10:47:51 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
    Setting default log level to "WARN".
    To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
        return f(*a, **kw)
      File "/home/hduser/PycharmProjects/Assignment2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
        format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.toDF.
    : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
    Old column names (1): _c0
    New column names (4): ownerid, houseid, zipcode, value
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.toDF(Dataset.scala:447)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/hduser/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/avg_value.py", line 15, in <module>
        .toDF(*columns)
      File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 2055, in toDF
        jdf = self._jdf.toDF(self._jseq(cols))
      File "/home/hduser/PycharmProjects/Assignment2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
        answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
      File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
        raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
    pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: "requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.\nOld column names (1): _c0\nNew column names (4): ownerid, houseid, zipcode, value"

    Process finished with exit code 1*
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54281899/spark-shell-the-number-of-columns-doesnt-match This looks relevant to your question. It has something to do with null values in your csv that needs to b e handled.Refer to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=read#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv as well to handle your case better.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified one line of my code & its working fine now.

```
df = spark.read \
 .format('csv') \
 .options(header='true').load('/home/hduser/Desktop/sample1/avg/input_avg.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem it could be the delimiter, I would recommend that you check on that.
In the results you are getting only one column, instead the 4 that you are expecting.

You can read the from Spark like:

`df = spark.read.option('delimiter', ',').csv(path_to_file)`

Its save as DataFrame, if you are saving through Glue then I recommend that you create the DynamicDataFrame.

You can check the examples in this url:

https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/write-read-csv-file-from-s3-into-dataframe/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).